# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column IS HAVING ISSUE

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, debugging

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
> 'employee_id' cannot be null (Connection: mysql, SQL: update
> `attendance_employees` set `employee_id` = ?, `date` = ?, `clock_in` =
> ?, `clock_out` = ?, `late` = -473049:00:00, `early_leaving` =
> 473058:00:00, `attendance_employees`.`updated_at` = 2023-12-19
> 16:23:08 where `id` = 2)

issue when i clock in its workk but when I clock out  have isue

`else

```
            {

                $overtime = '00:00:00';

            }



            $attendanceEmployee                = AttendanceEmployee::find($id);

            $attendanceEmployee->employee_id   = $request->employee_id;

            $attendanceEmployee->date          = $request->date;

            $attendanceEmployee->clock_in      = $request->clock_in;

            $attendanceEmployee->clock_out     = $request->clock_out;

            $attendanceEmployee->late          = $late;

            $attendanceEmployee->early_leaving = $earlyLeaving;

            $attendanceEmployee->overtime      = $overtime;

            $attendanceEmployee->total_rest    = '00:00:00';



            $attendanceEmployee->save();



            return redirect()->back()->with('success', __('Employee attendance successfully updated.'));

        }

    }

    else

    {

        return redirect()->back()->with('error', __('Employee are not allow multiple time clock in & clock for every day.'));

    }

}`
          **  $attendanceEmployee->save();**
```

The main issue is comming from clock in side error IN             **    $attendanceEmployee->save();

**
when user clock out it show this error

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question ..  There is no [Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here and I see no question ..  Just two very poorly written statements.  Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `'employee_id'` is present in the request before trying to update the record.

```
if (!$request->has('employee_id')) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', __('Employee ID is required.'));
}

$attendanceEmployee = AttendanceEmployee::find($id);
// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

In your DataTable, the "`employee_id`" column should not be null. Therefore, when inserting or updating a record, it is imperative to provide a `non-null` value for the "`employee_id`" field.

Comment: can you include some code to support your claim?

Comment: Just put this vaidation before process it


if (!empty($request->employee_id ?? '')) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', __('Employee ID is required.'));
}

$attendanceEmployee = AttendanceEmployee::find($id);